# Shape Keys: Best method for simple mouth shape

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, shape-keys, extrude

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Im trying to determine the best way to create the mouth animation of this hard working carrot! I will use shape keys, I’m just trying to create a clean mouth shape out of the Mesh. I’ve tried extruding faces (but shape isn’t great) as well as live sculpt but can’t really get a successful result (selected part of mesh not deforming well)

Here’s the GIF: https://giphy.com/gifs/carrot-14m3HcGbcy4v9m

I’ve also tried a Boolean operation but it creates sharp edges. What’s the best method to accomplish a mouth like this? Do I just need to get better at sculpting? :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes extrude inwards seems like the right thing to do, here is a quick try, make sure you have enough geometry. Also have you tried bones instead of shapekeys?

[image]

Comment: I would put 3 bones for the upper lip and 3 for the bottom one, something like that

Comment: On relook the  link does work from youtube https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&v=jEQoQ5DzPMI&redir_token=w-IV-prsLjebx3ugVGfm2e4qwNZ8MTU3NDQxNDg3MUAxNTc0MzI4NDcx&q=http%3A%2F%2Fperm.cessen.com%2F2010%2Fblenderartists%2Fmouth.blend, its 404 from the BA site. https://blenderartists.org/t/mouth-rig-simple-but-effective/491749   Well worth checking out.

Comment: @moonboots your loopcuts and inward extrude is perfect for this thank you! Only thing is, getting those loop cuts into circular shapes like in your screenshot above is throwing me for a...loop lol. I'm having to move each vertice into the right place, and its a little wonky because my mesh isn't 100% symmetrical. Is there an easier, more accurate approach? Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots sure thing thanks! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6875" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6875/)

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem, just select somes faces and extrude inwards, but maybe you should 1) keep a simpler topology and use Subsurf to smooth 2) use bones so that once you've created a character standing up you can make whatever you want with it: lay on the ground, move his leg, etc...

Comment: @moonboots Thanks so much. After using the Loop Cut Tools > Circle, insetting faces and then applying Subsuf on selected vertices, the shape turns out great. I applied original sub surf on the object previously to try and sculpt. I also created a two bone armature but might have hide it, thats a great idea to start off with it though. Appreciate your insight!